# How to use Background Tracking in Phonegap windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, cordova, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I am using Phonegap windows ph 8 background tracking and push notification

```
***<BackgroundExecution>
   <ExecutionType Name="LocationTracking" />
  </BackgroundExecution>***

     This is working properly in windows phone 8 but now we are support 8.1 while application is in background and any pushnotification received taped on toast my application is relaunched not resume.
```

Answer (score 0):

When running in the background on wp8.1 the location icon should be on. if not your app is sleeping.

You will need to install the backgroundMode plugin.

Note: Phonegap will not run in the background on wp8.1 but the location thread (backgroundMode plugin) will. What this means is you app will not receive any GPS updates. But it will resume from the background without restarting.